# ChartJS and Bootstrap 4 resize canvas according to dataset size

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I've managed to write a simple history log chart based on a PostgreSQL dataset. I've added a horizontal scrollbar by wrapping the `<canvas>` element into a `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="chart-container" style="overflow-x: scroll;height:300px;">
    <canvas id="chartid-1" style="height: 100%; width: 1000px "></canvas>
</div>
```

and also setting the `responsive: false` and `maintainAspectRatio: false` flags on chart instance to manually set the width/height of the canvas. With this method I have a fixed width and the scrollbar is always visible/active.

My problem is I want to dynamically resize the canvas based on dataset elements count, to have for example no scrollbar when the dataset is small , and instead increasing the width to expand the chart area when the dataset contains a lot of elements.

Is possible to do that client-side (eg. javascript/jquery) ?

I'm using latest versions of Bootstrap/jQuery/ChartJS.

thanks!